# How to make an DOM element be free of Jquery Mobile auto setting UI classes?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Maybe my question is a little confusing, let me clarify it a little.

I'm using Jquery Mobile, and I want to have it's screen transitions and other things, but I don't want all those UI styles automaticly applied to my elements.

My current problem is the **ui-link** applied to my links. The others *ui-whatever*, for the time being aren't bothering me.

**I want to avoid this issue in a "friendly way" (without rewriting a lot of CSS or removing them again).**

Is there any way of making an element immune to these auto-styling?

The code I wrote:

```
<div class="page" id="home" data-role="page">
   <a class="bt" href="#page2">Page Two</a>
</div>
```

The Jquery Mobile generated code

```
<div id="home" class="page ui-page ui-body-c ui-page-active" data-role="page" data-url="home" tabindex="0" style="min-height: 361px;">
   <a class="bt ui-link" href="#page2">Page Two</a>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it! Hope it can help someone with the same problem.

Just apply `data-role="none"` to the element.

> Preventing auto-initialization of form elements
>
> If you'd prefer that a particular form control be left untouched by
>   jQuery Mobile, simply give that element the attribute
>   data-role="none". For example:

```
<label for="foo">
<select name="foo" id="foo"  data-role="none">
    <option value="a" >A</option>
    <option value="b" >B</option>
    <option value="c" >C</option>
</select>
```

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/#/demos/1.0b2/docs/forms/docs-forms.html

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".ui-link").removeClass("ui-link");
```

That should remove the class from all that have it :-)

Comment: That's not the approach I need. Like I wrote, I need a way of making the element imune to those auto-styling

Comment: @MarceloAssis that might not be probable. you could always make another style sheet (instead of editing the jQuery one) that would have all your version of what the different styles should be and include it after the the jQuery one.

Comment: I hope it may be possible. I want to avoid any extra processing to solve that problem, because it's a mobile app and have to be fastest as possible.

Comment: @MarceloAssis you hope that **what** may be possible?

Comment: "My current problem is the ui-link applied to my links".  The Jquery applies a **ui-link** style to all my anchor elements, and I want avoid that. Only this. I want to say to Jquery: Don't apply any style to my anchors.

Comment: @MarceloAssis only way I can tell to combat jQuery is with **MORE JQUERY** or with a new stylesheet to overwrite theirs.

Comment: Me too, that's why I made this question. And I don't know JQ Mobile in depth, then, I'm hoping the JQ Enginers had made some option to customize that styling issue.